# Error with struct option: array type has incomplete element type

Tags: c, arrays, getopt-long

I try to build a function for parsing cmd line. But, when I define the `long_options` array I get the compile errors:

```
error: array type has incomplete element type
error: field name not in record or union initializer
error: (near initialization for 'long_options')
// and so on for every defined line in the 'long_options'
```

The code:

```
//parse_cmd.c
void parse_cmd(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    while (1) {
        int input_char;
        static struct option long_options[] = {
                {.name = "dev-name", .has_arg = 1, .val = 'd'},
                {.name = "tcp-port", .has_arg = 1, .val = 't'},
                {.name = "ib-port",  .has_arg = 1, .val = 'i'},
                {.name = "seed",     .has_arg = 1, .val = 's'},
                {.name = "iters",    .has_arg = 1, .val = 'I'},
                {.name = "mask",     .has_arg = 1, .val = 'm'},
                {.name = NULL,       .has_arg = 0, .val = '\0'}
        };
       }
}
```

Can you please help why I get these errors?

Comment: How does `struct option` look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you do:

```
#include <getopt.h>
```

in the beginning of the C file, to pull in the `getopt()` function prototyp and its related declarations, including `struct option`.